Kitchen spout thread sizes, American and Metric
I am trying to adapt metric to kitchen spout which has male threads and an aerator.
What are likely metric sizes?   I thought the metric equivalent of normal aerator was 22mm.  That is a bit too small.
25mm?
A i/2" x 20mm might work, but I couldn't find one, but not sure.  I bought a set of various size adaptors, but none worked.  I thought this would be a frequently used adaptor.  Help?

Please post some photos, mention the model of your tap etc.

Metric and American threads do not match together, even if the same size.  Is there a problem of getting the right thread type, instead of trying to adapt?  Usually to get american to metric the threads need recutting plus reducing/increasing the size, or need male american to male metric adapter, which would probably look ugly.

As others have said, for plumbing parts there are not metric to standard adapters that work.  The demand is far too low. Just get the proper metric size you need.
